# PHP loop to get the data I need

Tags: php, arrays

I am using an API and am using a few foreach loops to get to the stage that I am at right now. Please see code below with my comments and also the results that I am getting below that.

```
// get recent_games api data
$recent_games_data = $player->recent_games();

//start arrays for below
$matches = array();
$gameType = array();
$myData = array();

// using foreach loops to dig in to api data
foreach($recent_games_data['gameStatistics']['array'] as $key_match_data => $value_match_data) {
    $matches[] = $value_match_data['statistics'];
}
foreach($matches as $key_match) {
    $gameType[] = $key_match['array'];
}
foreach ($gameType as $keyz) {
    $myData[] = $keyz;
}
```

The $mydata array outputs this data below.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [statType] => TRUE_DAMAGE_DEALT_TO_CHARACTER
                [dataVersion] => 0
                [value] => 3351
                [futureData] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [statType] => ASSISTS
                [dataVersion] => 0
                [value] => 14
                [futureData] => 
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [statType] => NUM_DEATHS
                [dataVersion] => 0
                [value] => 3
                [futureData] => 
            )
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [statType] => TRUE_DAMAGE_DEALT_TO_CHARACTER
                [dataVersion] => 0
                [value] => 331
                [futureData] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [statType] => ASSISTS
                [dataVersion] => 0
                [value] => 4
                [futureData] => 
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [statType] => NUM_DEATHS
                [dataVersion] => 0
                [value] => 7
                [futureData] => 
            )
    )
```

Of course there is much more data but this is basically what I have now. The first array [0] is **each match** and the second array are the **statistics** for that match. What I want is how do I get the statistics of each match without hardcoding the match array number, for example below.

```
  $myData[0][0]['statType']
```

Let me know if you need more info and thank you.

EDIT: sorry for to mention that as new statistics data gets added to the api, the index number changes. IE TRUE_DAMAGE_DEALT_TO_CHARACTER is [0] to begin with but then may change to [1] or [2] etc.

Comment: you should consider working with model classes in stead of building a huge associative array. It might be a little bit more work at first, but it will make coding and maintenance so much easier. This is why OOP was invented!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need several foreach loops - you can add to all three arrays in a single one. Also, it looks like $gameType and $myData end up containing the same data.

```
foreach($recent_games_data['gameStatistics']['array'] as $key_match_data => $value_match_data) {
    $matches[] = $value_match_data['statistics'];
    $gameType[] = $value_match_data['statistics']['array'];
    $myData[] = $value_match_data['statistics']['array'];
}
```

I don't really understand why you don't just put it into the same array so you can access it easily, though:

```
foreach($recent_games_data['gameStatistics']['array'] as $key_match_data => $value_match_data) {
    $matches[] = array('statistics' => $value_match_data['statistics'], 'data' => $value_match_data['statistics']['array']);
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, that does make a lot of sense - I guess I was getting a tad frustrated and starting doing bad code just to get it working for now and then intended to clean it later. I've added a comment above, will paste here for you to see.

sorry for to mention that as new statistics data gets added to the api, the index number changes. IE TRUE_DAMAGE_DEALT_TO_CHARACTER is [0] to begin with but then may change to [1] or [2] etc.

Comment: In that case, you may want to rewrite the data you receive from the API, so that instead of having `[0] => Array ( [statType] => ASSISTS )` etc, you use `$someArray['assists'] = array('dataversion' => $someVal, 'value' => $someVal /* etc */);`. That way, you can easily update `$matches[5]['assists'] = array(/* new values */);` or similarly.

Comment: This helped big time as I have just made a breakthrough, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider implementing a class for your stats items after parsing through the data (independent of individual match information keys):

```
class Stat_Item {
    function __construct($id, $info) {
        $this->id = $id;

        if(!empty($info['damage'])
            $this->damage_dealt = $info['damage'];

        if(!empty($info['assists']))
            $this->assists = $info['assists'];

        if(!empty($info['deaths']))
            $this->deaths = $info['deaths'];
    }
}

$parsed_items = array();

foreach($mydata as $match_id => $match) {
    $info = array();

    foreach($match as $data_point) {
        switch($data_point['statType']) {
            case TRUE_DAMAGE_DEALT_TO_CHARACTER:
                $info['damage'] = $data_point['value'];

                break;

            case ASSISTS:
                $info['assists'] = $data_point['value'];

                break;

            case NUM_DEATHS:
                $info['deaths'] = $data_point['value'];

                break;
        }

        $parsed_items[] = new Stat_Item($match, $info);
    }
}
```

Other than looping through them all, I don't see any way for you to get a particular match without calling it by its `index`.

Comment: I've added more info on this, which will make the above invalid - thanks though!

Comment: Updated my answer with another potential solution.

Comment: This looks good - I'm definitely going to consider this. Thanks for the help